# Cant launch my program for Windows Phone 7.1 with Emulator on Windows Phone SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm trying to load my program with with buided in emulator in Windows phone SDK.

But when emulator starts loading program it just show me a splash screen with no progress. I tried to debug it. But i simply dont know where i need to set start breakpoint. Ive already debugged many of program parts with no effect.

Im using Visual Studio 2010 as IDE.

Comment: What happens if you try to run some other program?

Comment: No problems with other programs.